# Method does not support request body:GET

Tags: java, android

```
 class MySync extends AsyncTask{ ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    protected void onPreExecute(){
       mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading...", "Data is Loading...");
    }
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params)  {
        int result = 0;
       //String url="http://192.168.0.108:8080/sbi/login?"+"key1="+params[0]+"&key2="+params[1]";
        int code;
        try {
            URL hp=new URL("http://192.168.0.108:8080/sbi/login?"+"key1="+params[0]+"&key2="+params[1]);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)hp.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            Log.i("A", "connect");
            code=urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            Log.i("A","code");
            boolean a=check(code);

           if(a){
                //urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                Log.i("A", "input");
               // urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                Log.i("A", "output");
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                Log.i("A", "get");
                byte [] buf=("key1=" + params[0] + "&key2=" + params[1]).getBytes();
                urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(buf);
                Log.i("A", "sent");
            }
            else{
                Log.i("A","error");
                result=3;
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.i("e", "Error");
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    protected boolean check(int c){
            if(c==200) return true;
            else return false;
        }
   }
```

This code gives error method does not support a request body:get? also if i insert setdooutput(true) then it gives error already connected. I am newbie to android and i am making my college project

Comment: Http get method doesn't support having request body, if you want to pass key value pairs with get you need to pass them with the Url

Comment: What if you remove `urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(buf);` and try not using `setDoOutput`.

Comment: it seems you are trying to "post" data over OutputStream. check with changing setRequestMethod parameter from "GET" to "POST"

Comment: it tells java.net.ProtocolException: method does not support a request body:POST

Comment: kindly tell me how to pass through key value pair

Answer (score 3):

if you really want to send key value pairs to server in request body then change

```
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

to

```
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Or if the server doesn't support `POST` but requires you to do `GET` then remove the lines

```
byte [] buf=("key1=" + params[0] + "&key2=" + params[1]).getBytes();
urlConnection.getOutputStream().write(buf);
```

As I can see from this line

```
URL hp=new URL("http://192.168.0.108:8080/sbi/login?"+"key1="+params[0]+"&key2="+params[1]);
```

You are already building the Url correctly for a `GET` Http request, but you are adding a request body to a HTTP request method that doesn't support request body (`GET` http method in this case).

Take a look at [this wikipidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) page for more details on REST and REST with HTTP/S to get a more detailed idea on this architecture

Comment: what if i want to send through post? can you provide me some basic code please

Comment: @MayankSingh I already answered that here, if you want to send through `POST` just change the request method like I said in the answer `urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");`

Comment: A request method which doesn't allow a request body looks quite useless to me. What am I missing? How to specify which item to choose (when used for a api-query)?

Comment: `GET`  request by design of the HTTP standard doesnt allow request body, if you want to pass some information to server in a `GET` request you would need to construct a query string like `https://blah.com/getsomething?id=12,name="martin"` so the back end will then be able to recieve these parameters from the query.

Answer (score 0):

prepare URL Connection as below

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) (url.openConnection());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

call

```
String dataToSend = "(\"key1=\" + params[0] + \"&key2=\" + params[1])";
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");// do not use "GET" in your case

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");//whatever you want

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + dataToSend.getBytes().length);

conn.setUseCaches(false);//set true to enable Cache for the req
conn.setDoOutput(true);//enable to write data to output stream
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(dataToSend.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

dot forget to call below method after all

```
conn.connect();
```